# Progress 4gl. Creating a Combo Box inside a Browse

Tags: combobox, progress-4gl, openedge

How do I create a static combo box inside a browse ?

example output that i would like to display:

`column 1` `combo-box1` `column 2` `column3` `combo-box2`

side note:
would also like to know how to add a dynamic combo box.

Answer (score 3):

You can define the cell as a combo-box in the DEFINE BROWSE statement.

```
DEFINE BROWSE brComboBox
  QUERY qTT DISPLAY
    fieldA
    fieldB
    fieldC VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX LIST-ITEMS "a,b,c,d"
    fieldD 
      ENABLE fieldC
    WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 70 BY 4.5 FONT 10 FIT-LAST-COLUMN.
```

If you're working with the AppBuilder GUI you simply edit the DISPLAY portion of the browse so it contains all fields:

```
  fieldA
  fieldB
  fieldC VIEW-AS COMBO-BOX LIST-ITEMS "a,b,c,d"
  fieldD 
    ENABLE fieldC
```

Comment: when i tried the 2nd code with freeform query, it gives error message `"unable to understand after -- 'fieldB fieldC '" 247` if i remove the `view-as...` then it will run but no combo-box

Comment: What version are you on? The code works exactly as expected for me, are you sure you are copying it without changes and have a temp-table defined?

Comment: we are using 9.1E and yes.. i created temp-table TT and all fields use CHAR. created freeform query with open query browse-name for each TT. then on display trigger, i added the fields